# What are /dev/sda1 and /dev/sda2 on an Amazon EC2 instance?

Tags: amazon-ec2, amazon-web-services, diskmanagement

I have an Amazon EC2 instance which according to the management console has no EBS volumes attached to it. Yet, when I run `df` I see `/dev/sda1` and `\dev\sda2` both are "disk"s. What are they? Is one the `instance-store`? If so then what is the other?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

/dev/sda1 and /dev/sda2 are the local ephemeral storage disks

If you look here http://docs.amazonwebservices.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/instance-storage-concepts.html you'll see the various details about what's mounted where.

- /dev/sda1 would be the 10Gb root partition
- /dev/sda2 would be the 150Gb /mnt partition.

Answer (score 0):

Run
`mount`
or `cat /proc/mount`

That should get you started. It will list the device name or UUID and the mount point. The reality of the matter on EC2 is that they are probably just bits from a BIG bucket of bits somewhere, but your OS thinks they are SCSI or SATA disk drives.